# SpringVaadinSession ClassCastException to VaadinSession

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, vaadin

> EDIT: I have tracked it down to be related with @Push annotation used on the jetty maven plugin. This exception only occurs on "hot deploy", i.e. if we do not restart the jetty server between code changes but use the reload feature of it. It is still an issue, but a full jetty restart avoids it (ofc. sacrificing the faster refresh speed with hot deploy). As long as i don't need @Push, I deactivate it for testing and all is fine.

I'm using flow 10.0.6 to build a combined Spring/Vaadin UI (which also includes a rest controller). Therefore im using the Spring dispatcher servlet, which is responsable of routing paths to the vaadinServlet.

For testing I use jetty:run via Maven, running the jetty-maven-plugin 9.4.12.v20180830 with manual reload (manualtrue)

Works fine so far, but when I have the app already running and then reload manually after some code changes, i get the following exception (full stack trace below): javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession

Soooo ... What i tried alredy:

- vaadin 11.0.1
- different Browsers (ff, chrome)
- vaadin forum (in parallel: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17331831/17331832)

But this error seems so far baked-in that i run out of ideas what else to try. I would really aprreciate some help here :)

Greetings, Markus

Full Stack Trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:302) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566) [jetty-security-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:163) ~[jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:73) ~[jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na] 
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1535) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1498) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:300) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na] 
... 79 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.readFromHttpSession(VaadinService.java:2071) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.loadSession(VaadinService.java:2051) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.getExistingSession(VaadinService.java:942) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.doFindOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:791) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:766) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:624) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1480) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na] 
... 80 common frames omitted
```